# How to run a dart task in IO Task Runner

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to run a task in the real thread.
Share with memory and non-block in UI Runner.
Can dart do it?
Isolate has no shared memory.

Comment: If it's not a long running task you can use a "Future" or an "Async/Await" function.

Comment: Thanks, but it is long running task.

Comment: Dart does not have threads that share memory as other programming languages do, you can either use Futures, Async/Await functions or look into isolates and how to communicate between isolates.

Comment: Ok, Futures, Async/Await and isolates are not good for long running task

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/concurrency

Comment: Isolates are good for long running tasks but Futures and Async/Await functions are not.

Comment: As @JorgeZ points out, Isolates are great for long running tasks as they do in fact run on a separate thread (and typically on a separate CPU core if the device has one), so they are the only true multi-tasking paradigm in Dart (async/await are 'faking it' and are mostly to prevent I/O blocking).  The only issue is that Isolates do not share memory, so there is a small overhead in setting up an Isolate if you need to transfer a lot of memory to the Isolate (returning a large block *from* the Isolate is fast since Dart 2.15).  Dart does not have the concept of threads with shared memory).

Answer (score 0):

With Flutter 2.8 and Dart 2.15 were introduced isolated groups where used shared memory and exchange between isolates in same group are 10x-100x faster than in separated isolate.